# Does Snowflake provide an entry or exit point for Tor users?

Tags: torcheck

Snowflake is an extension that enhances the Tor service.

Does Snowflake provide entry or exit points for Tor users?

Comment: Snowflakes provide an entry point to the Tor network. Is there more specific information that you want to know? https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/anti-censorship/pluggable-transports/snowflake/-/wikis/Technical%20Overview

Comment: THX. Pls write a short answer. So you can get the 50 points from bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake offers entry points to the network.

"The snowflake client and snowflake proxy may also be referred to as snowflake peers.
In Snowflake, WebRTC occurs only between the snowflake peers: some snowflake client and some snowflake in-browser proxy, as WebRTC serves as the transport crossing the filter boundary. Communication from the proxy to the destination is currently via websocket. Communication to the Broker is over HTTPS / Domain Fronting."

https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/anti-censorship/pluggable-transports/snowflake/-/wikis/Technical%20Overview